# How to use Application_UnhandledException to catch general Exceptions?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone

I'm asking something that is probabily quite simple, but I'm sure I am missing something here :D

I have the following method in my App.xaml.cs file:

```
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("An error occurred!", ":(", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    e.Handled = true;
    App.Current.Terminate;
}
```

And the eventHandler is added in the App() method:

```
public App()
{
    UnhandledException += Application_UnhandledException;

    //InitializeComponent() etc...
}
```

Now, I added a couple of lines that generate an IndexOutOfRange Exception in one of my methods in my MainPage.xaml.cs file, something like:

```
int[] stuff = new int[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    stuff[i] = 0;
}
```

I don't understand how the Application_UnhandledException method works, since when I try to run that, I get the IndexOutOfRange Exception in the Visual Studio debugger, but then the app crashes and I don't get that message box, so the code inside the Application_UnhandledException doesn't run at all.
Why is that?

Is there a way to add an event handler that triggers with whatever exception I get? 
I mean, with an IndexOutOfRande, with a KeyNotFound and so on...

Thanks! :)

Comment: What happens when you wrap a try/catch around the code and within the catch re-throw the exception.

Comment: Nothing happens, I get the same IndexOutOfRange Exception, and the Application_UnhandledException doesn't get triggered.

Comment: Is the code contained within an asynchronous function?

Comment: See reference: [Application.UnhandledException event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.unhandledexception.aspx)

Comment: Yup it was contained in an async method. I tried to add that in another method that wasn't async but the result was the same :/

Answer (score 1):

Your message box does not show because it closes the app right afterwards.

In case you want to stop this behavior, you need this line of code:

```
e.Handled = true;
```

However as stated above, continuing with app execution can lead to more problems. So I would use this only for scenarios where you collect the crash info, maybe apologize to the user and then quit the app anyway using `App.Current.Terminate();`

Comment: I added that after the message box, and I also added App.Current.Terminate(), but it doesn't work, the point is that the whole Application_UnhandledException method doesn't get triggered.
I tried with an IndexOutOfRange Exception and with a KeyNotFound Exception, it doesn't work.
I mean, is it possible to create an event handler that triggers with ANY kind of Exception I can get?

Comment: This method should be called every time. Could you try to create new app and produce exception here?

Comment: I tried that but I still get the same thing: Visual Studio tells me I got an IndexOutOfRange Exception, but the Application_UnhandledException method doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.unhandledexception.aspx) that Musters linked it says the following:

> Normally after the UnhandledException event is fired, the Windows
>   Runtime terminates the app because the exception was unhandled. The
>   app code has some control over this: if the UnhandledException event
>   handler sets the Handled property of the event arguments to true, then
>   in most cases the app will not be terminated. However, doing so
>   routinely is not recommended for several reasons:
>
> > • Typically the UnhandledException event handler doesn’t have enough information to
> >     know whether continuing on after an exception is safe. Parts of the
> >     application code or the Windows Runtime may be in an inconsistent
> >     state, which could result in subsequent failures if the app continues
> >     running its code.
> >
> > • The Windows Runtime considers exceptions
> >     encountered during certain operations as nonrecoverable, because the
> >     Windows Runtime itself will be in an inconsistent state following
> >     these exceptions. For such exceptions, even if the UnhandledException
> >     event handler sets Handled to true, the app will still be terminated.
> >
> > • Errors that happen during navigation could cause a state where
> >     there's nothing loaded as content and nothing to indicate to the user
> >     that the app is still running.

Comment: If you are running with the debugger attached make sure that you continue through the execution of the your application because the UnhandledException event is not fired until after you receive the initial notification from the Visual Studio debugger.